# Device Emulator not recognized in windows when I press cradle

Tags: visual-studio-2008, pocketpc, windows-7-x64, device-emulation

Who can help me with this: I am working on Win7 x64, with VS.net 2008. I am developping for pocketpc.

When my application is deployed to the device emulator it can't connect to my computer / db server. Both de emulator as well the mobile device center are configured to use DMA. When I cradle the device using device manager, nothing happens.

What can I try?

Comment: Has anyone managed to "cradle" on Windows 8.1 x64?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This guy seems to have the same problem on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsoftdeviceemu/thread/325d37ae-30ad-4ec5-9dab-ff645925d440?prof=required&ppud=4).

Update: Finally tested this out.  It works however i still needed to do a bunch of crazy stuff.

1. I needed to install the regular version of [Virtual PC SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=28C97D22-6EB8-4A09-A7F7-F6C7A1F000B5&displaylang=en) *after* I followed the steps described in this [article](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx).  This requires a number of donwloads, installs, restarts, etc...  It also requires that you use IE because of all of the ActiveX crap and Windows Genuine stuff.
2. Then I needed to fire up an emulator with the emulator manager, select file, config and enable networking.
3. Next i needed to open my network connection properties and enable virtual network connections.  Described in greater detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/01/15/fixing-broken-virtual-networking.aspx).
4. Having done all of this, you can now cradle the device in the emulator manager.  Now in the Windows Mobile Device Manager you should notice that it is connecting to your device.  Additionally the internet on the device seems to work w/o any special setup since it piggybacks off of your local pc connection (connecting without cradling is another story from what i understand...)

The reasoning for the complexity of all of this is as follows, if understand correctly:

- You need the virtual network adapter (for obvious reasons)
- MS no longer offers the DL as a standalone, but bundles it with Virtual PC (only 30 megs so no big deal)
- The Virtual PC installer broke with Vista (mostly installs just fine but silently fails for at least virtual network adapters if not other components)
- Apparently it is still broken in 7 and must be worked around via the above or similar routine (apparently it's possible to [manually install](http://www.brianpeek.com/blog/archive/2009/05/02/windows-virtual-pc-and-the-microsoft-device-emulator.aspx) the driver sans Virtual PC but that seemed more tricky to me...)

Further helpful discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsoftdeviceemu/thread/6d9538ba-8d12-49ae-956d-af9f787d6b58).

And there you have it.

brian